# Best practices for optimizing the structure of parquet schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

There is a lot of talk that in order to really benefit from fast queries over parquet and hdfs, we need to make sure that the data is stored in a manner that is friendly to compression.

Unfortunately, I did not find any specific guidelines or tips online that describe do-s and dont-s in designing the parquet schema.

I did watch the youtube videos that describe dictionary encoding, RLE, pushdown filtering, partitions,..

I am wondering that perhaps someone here can either share sych material or his or her own experience regarding this.

For example:

I have the following logical structure that I want to store:

```
{
     root: [
         [int, int float, float],
         [int, int float, float],
         [int, int float, float],
         ....,
         .....
     ]          
}
```

This is of course a list of lists. All the sublists are actually vectors of the same length where the coordinates match in meaning and type.

If I understand correctly, the best way to *store* this structure is by going for the columnar paradigm, where I will have 4 very long vectors, one for each coordinate. rather than many vectors that are short.

What other consideration can I apply?